# onChange doesn't fire for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, dynamic, onchange

I have 3 input texts , and I would like to do some operations between the first 2 , and print the result in the 3. The content of the first input text is generated by a query , gets data from a database , so the content is generated dynamicly. So my case would be for example : ( first input text - 3) minus ( second input text 0 ) = ( result input text 0 );
This is part of my code I used to do this :

```
$(document).on('change input load', '#act_hrs_1e', function() { var_hrs('act_hrs_1e','plan_hrs_1e','var_hrs_1e'); });
```

My problem is that none of change , input or load doesn't work for the dynamicly generated content (in my example is 3) , what I want is that when I load the page , it does the operation without any need to input something to fire the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to separate the `load` event from that code, you are delegating the `load` event from the `document` object to an element with id `#act_hrs_1e`, this should work:

```
function callHrs() {
    var_hrs('act_hrs_1e','plan_hrs_1e','var_hrs_1e'); 
}

$(document).on('ready', callHrs).on('change input', '#act_hrs_1e', callHrs);
```

Comment: var_hrs is already a function , is the function I use to do the difference between first input text ( id  - act_hrs_1e) and the second input text ( plan_hrs_1e)  and after I write it in the third input text ( id var_hrs_1e )

Comment: Then the first part of my answer is only relevant. Separate the load event from the other two events. Ill change the function name to not cause confusion.

Comment: It doesn't work.. this is what I did :      $(document).on('load', var_hrs).on('change input', '#act_hrs_1e', var_hrs('act_hrs_1e','plan_hrs_1e','var_hrs_1e'));

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are scoping the event down to an object with ID of act_hrs_1e, you should only ever have one element with that ID. Try scoping to a css class or removing the scope to respond to the event for all elements.

Comment: I have only one element with that ID , in that part i call that ids because are the arguments of my var function ( difference between first two , and write the result in the third)